# Apify selector for dynamic class name

Tags: web-scraping, jquery-selectors, selector, apify

I'm trying to scrape div, which has dynamically generated class name.

class_name_1234
class_name_2345
class_name_3456

Can you help me please?
Is there any possibility to choose by querySelector even those classes which can be identified only by the common beginning of the name?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a CSS selector that lets you search for an attribute that begins with a specific string:

`[attribute^=value]`

In your case:

`[class^="class_name_"]`

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp